# combine array and object values and find same values for table

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, frontend

I have an object

```
 const objectForMapping = {
          "001": "Street",
          "002": "Name",
          "003": "Town"
          },
```

and array with objects

```
    const arrayOfValues = [
            {
              "questionCode": "002",
              "value": "Thomas"
            },
{
              "questionCode": "001",
              "value": "First"
            },
{
              "questionCode": "003",
              "value": "Mexico"
            }
          ],
```

I want to create table where I need to check if questionCode is present in objectForMapping key and in table I will show an object value connected with the key as label. For example it will look like this

- Name: Thomas
- Street: First
- Town: Mexico

my code I have just correct description not label

```
{arrayOfValues.map((element, key) => (
          <Line label={element.questionCode} description={element.value}
            key={key}/> 
        ))}
```

Comment: `objectForMapping[element.questionCode]`?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
label={element.questionCode}
```

You want

```
label={objectForMapping[element.questionCode]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you need something like this?

```
{arrayOfValues.map((element, key) => (
          <Line label={objectForMapping[element.questionCode]} description={element.value}
            key={key}/> 
        ))}
```